# Query return null instead of a result with some record

Tags: sql

I'm sorry, perhaps this question is simple but I can't solve it.

I have 3 tables:

- `users` (`id, name`)
- `resumes` (`id, title, users_id_fk`)
- `comments` (`id, comment, resumes_id_fk`)

Now these tables have these records:

- `users` { (1, N1), (2, N2)} ==> 2 users
- `resumes` { (1, title1, 1), (2, title2, 1)}  ==> 2 resumes
- `comments` {(1, Comment, 2)} ==> 1 comment

I want to execute a query that returns title and count of comments for a specific user resume:

```
SELECT 
   u.name, r.title, count(c.comment)
from 
   users u, resumes r, comments c
where 
   c.id = r.id 
   and r.id = u.id 
   and u.id = 2
group by 
   u.name, r.title;
```

Problem is that my excepted result is: `{(N2, ,0)}`

But returned `{(,,)}`

My SQL is not good, pls.

Comment: Those join conditions don't look correct. Shouldn't it be `c.resumes_id_fk = r.id AND r.users_id_fk = u.id AND u.id = 2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using **INNER JOIN**, change to **LEFT JOIN** will fix your problem.

```
SELECT u.name, r.title, count(c.comment)
from users u
left join resumes r on r.users_id_fk =u.id
left join comments c on c.resumes_id_fk = r.id
where u.id = 2
group by u.name, r.title
```

And your join condition is wrong too.